# Can I trust X-Forwarded-For header value when whitelisting IP address?

Tags: security, spring-cloud-gateway, whitelist

I'm trying to add IP whitelisting feature on a gateway.
(I'm using Spring cloud gateway but I think the framework is not important when it comes to implementing this feature)

Most of the implementation use `X-Forwarded-For`
HTTP header value to verify the client IP address. **But I'm curious this is a secure way because someone in the middle (such as a proxy) could be tampering with this value so I think we should not trust this value**. Or is there another way to implementing it?
Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the infrastructure and your cloud provider. E.g. we're using AWS and they clearly document what headers are set by their proxy and to what value. In that case, I'd trust them.